# Remove extensions and redirect with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have this

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s\/(\w+).php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ /$1.php [L]
```

This removes `.php` extension and if user directly type `test.php` in browser will load `test`. So far so good.

Now I trying to make also if user type in browser this `http://example.com/test.php?page=something` to redirect and load `http://example.com/test/something`. Is this possible?

Comment: Your current code is "strange". Why the first two lines?

Comment: Because if user directly write `test.php` will redirect and load `test`..

Comment: Why would one want to do such thing? And what is `test` meant to be internally? You only rewrite that to `test.php` in the next line again...

Comment: First line with `%{THE_REQUEST}` prevent endless loops.

Comment: Sure, but still you first redirect from `test.php` to just `test`, only to rewrite internally to `test.php` again. but whatever :-)

Comment: One is for the page when is clicked on link to rewrite it without extension. Other one is when user type the page directly in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need additional rules for handle a parameter:

```
RewriteEngine On

# handle one parameter redirect rule
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(\w+)\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php?page=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```